# Prevent immediate change in Realm Database

Tags: android, realm

I have data in recycler view which I am getting from Realm database. And in my view holder(of recyclerview), I am having android Switch Compact, but i do not want to make immediate change in the database once status of the switch compact changed, I do have "Save" button which will be used to save all the changes done by user. As of now I must have to make switch status in database to reflect the same in recyclerview. Do we have any way which allows us to make changes in list(got from Realm result) used in recycler view, but does not update in Realm database.

Comment: Why not keep the new pending state in a map by primary key to boolean?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: thanks for the quick reply.
 you mean to say add new parameter in table for temporary state?

Comment: Not in table, I figured in memory should suffice and you can bind the new temporary state to adapter if exists, and the original state if doesn't - then on save, update the objects by key set (of primary keys) of the map to Realm

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Once again thanks. If possible could you please let me know the way of implementation for the same. It would be helpful. Any link for the reference will also be helpful.